# iPad mini model 1454 not supported LTE

Tags: ipad, cellular-carriers, cellular-data, lte

today I went to my services provider to get the 4G network to my iPad mini and I was just knowing that the 4G will not working with ipad mini model A1454 except in USA and Canada what should I do to get the 4G I'm so disappointed by this , I appreciate ur help within these.

Thnx 
Ghazi

Comment: Have you purchased an iPad already and are learning the limitations of the model you were sold or are you hoping to get pointed to this article where you can see which model you wish to buy? http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply but i already have my iPad mini model is mentioned above is there anyway to use the 4G with my model or not ?

Answer (score 4):

The iPad Mini model A1454 is designed and will only work on LTE bands 4 (AWS) and 17 (700b MHz).

- http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/

Since [4G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G) means so much, you may have to ask your specific carrier if they use either of these LTE bands. Even if your carrier operates in those bands, there still isn't a guarantee they support iPad so you'd really need to research that with them directly (or at least consult their website).

In addition to LTE, the mini is listed as supporting these other data protocols and frequencies at http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/

- GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)
- UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz)

In the US - these bands are marketed as 4G from AT&T and speeds are possible to overlap with LTE speeds even without connecting over LTE. If you are disappointed with your purchase, hopefully the vendor can assist you with a return or at worst, you can work on selling your iPad since new devices with no scratches can often sell for list price or even higher in some circumstances.